# remove white space between specific characters using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex to remove white spaces in the sequence of consecutive '?' and/or '!' in a string. One example is that "what is that ?? ? ? ?? ??? ? ! ! ! ? !" should be changed to "what is that ??????????!!!?!". That is, I want to concatenate all '?' and '!' without space in between. My current code doesn't work out well:

```
import re
s = "what is that ?? ? ? ?? ??? ? ! ! ! ? !"
s = re.sub("\? +\?", "??", s)
s = re.sub("\? +\!", "?!", s)
s = re.sub("\! +\!", "!!", s)
s = re.sub("\! +\?", "!?", s)
```

which produces 'what is that ??? ???????!! !?!', where some spaces are obviously not deleted. what is going wrong in my code and how to revise it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're simply trying to condense whitespace around the punctuation, yeah?  How about something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "what is that ?? ? ? ?? ??? ? ! ! ! ? !"
>>> 
>>> re.sub('\s*([!?])\s*', r'\1', s)
'what is that??????????!!!?!'
```

If you're really interested in *why* your approach isn't working, it has to do with how regular expressions move through a string.  When you write `re.sub("\? +\?", "??", s)` and run it on your string, the engine works through like this:

```
s = "what is that ?? ? ? ?? ??? ? ! ! ! ? !"
# first match -----^^^
# internally, we have:
s = "what is that ??? ? ?? ??? ? ! ! ! ? !"
# restart scan here -^
# next match here ----^^^
# internally:
s = "what is that ??? ??? ??? ? ! ! ! ? !"
# restart scan here ---^
# next match here ------^^^
```

And so on.  There are ways you can prevent the cursor from advancing as it's checking for a match (check out positive look-ahead).

Comment: This is one of the best solutions I could find. It has still a small issue for me which is that for `This is! ? a test! ?` it will return  `This is!?a test!?` while I expect to have `This is!? a test!?` (keep the space between the question mark and the 'a'). Any further help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want as @g.d.d.c said and sentence pattern is same then  then you can try this :

```
string_="what is that ?? ? ? ?? ??? ? ! ! ! ? !"
string_1=[]
symbols=[]
string_1.append(string_[:string_.index('?')])
symbols.append(string_[string_.index('?'):])
string_1.append("".join(symbols[0].split()))
print("".join(string_1))
```

output:

```
what is that ??????????!!!?!
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach involves splitting the string into two and then handling the problem area with regex (removing spaces) and then joining the pieces back together.

`import re
s = "what is that ?? ? ? ?? ??? ? ! ! ! ? !"
splitted = s.split('that ') # don't forget to add back in 'that' later
splitfirst = splitted[0]
s = re.sub("\s+", "", splitted[1])
finalstring = splitfirst+'that '+s
print(finalstring)`

output:

`╭─jc@jc15  ~/.projects/tests
╰─$ python3 string-replace-question-marks.py
what is that ??????????!!!?!`